# http service in angular sends post data as the key of the request body with no value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, api, express

I'm building an angular application and I'm using the $http service. When I send a post request to my node api my post data appears as the key to req.body with an empty string as the value.

On logging my req.body and req.headers on my server side I get this

```
{ '{"username":"niccolo","password":"pass123"}': '' } //req.body
{ host: 'localhost:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '43',
  accept: '*/*',
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  referer: 'http://localhost:3000/login',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8' } //req.header
```

Below is the service that makes the request

```
angular.module('dochub.services').service('Auth', ['$http', '$rootScope',function($http, $rootScope){
  this.login = function(user, cb){
    config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': '*/*'
      }
    }
    req = $http.post($rootScope.apiBaseUrl+'users/login', user, config);
    req.success(function(data){
      cb(data);
    })
  }
  this.logout = function(cb){
    cb(data);
  }
}]);
```

Also when I made a request to that endpoint using PostMan it worked properly so I guess the problem has to be with my angular code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using body-parser with express

Try this

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var parser = require('body-parser');

app.use(parser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(parser.json());
```

You can use the default Content-Type with $http

```
'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your Content-Type header in angular from

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

to

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

That should fix it.